# Display a loading directive while loading a file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, directive

I want to display a loading icon when I upload an image larger than 4MB to my program.  I am currently trying to use `mdDialog` although that may not be what I need to do.  So the section of code that this is occurring is `if (fileSize < 8000000 && fileSize > 4000000)`.  However the directive loading animation isn't appearing properly.  So I am not sure how to make that happen?

image-upload

```
if (fileSize > 8000000) {
  uploader.clearQueue();
  console.log("Error, the selected file is too large.  Image must be less than 8MB.")
}
else if (fileSize < 8000000 && fileSize > 4000000) {
  $mdDialog.show({
    templateUrl: 'controls/load-animate/load-animate-directive.tpl.html',
    controllerAs: 'loadAnimate'
  });
  fileItem.formData = [
    {
      "targetEntityId": $scope.targetEntityId,
      "entityType": $scope.entityType
    }
  ];
  $mdDialog.hide();
  $scope.uploader.uploadAll();
}
```

load-animate-directive.tpl.html

```
<div id="load-animate-contain" class="layout-column layout-align-center-center">
  <div class="layout-column layout-align-center-center">
    <img id="load-circle-top" class="its-spinning" src="/images/img.loadCircle-top.png" />
    <img id="load-circle-bottom" src="/images/img.loadCircle-bottom.png" />
    <p class="m2head its-blinking">Loading...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You provided an objective...and a bunch of code...but no problem statement related to that code or any question

Comment: might consider using an angular broadcast event that you listen for in directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fileUploadCtrl() you could do something like set $scope.loading = true/false based on where you are in the process, then in your view do

```
<load-animate ... ng-show="loading"></load-animate>
```